# Android EditText onTouch Event

Tags: android, android-edittext, touch-event

I have a Layout like this:

Parent: `RelativeLayout` with `onTouchListener`

Child: `EditText` witch match `RelativeLayout`

So, the `EditText` fills the `RelativeLayout`. I now don't want to insert/allow input in `EditText`. My aim is to fire the `onTouchListener` of the layout. But it won't fire.
I tried different options for the `EditText`:

1. `setEditable(false)` and `setFocusable(false)`
   -> OK, so no input, but also no `onTouch()`
2. `setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener){return false});`
   -> as far as I understand it, this should work in combination with option 1. but still not `TouchEvent` in `RelativeLayout`.

`TextViews` work with no problems but i think it is because they don't use `onTouch` oder `onClick`. What can i do that EditViews (or Views that intercept touchEvents) don't intercept the touchEvent?

Why all this: I want to move the `RelativeLayout` when the user touches it. This works fine as long as I don't put children in it that match parent.

Maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should override the onTouchEvent method of your EditText and return false. It worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing some code it´s hard to give a good example. Your could do:

```
     yourEditText.setEnabled(false);
```

and enable it if You need(setEnabled(true);)

Or override OnTouchListener:

```
     yourEditText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                 @override
                 public boolean onTouch(){

                 }
       });
```

Don´t write anything iside onTouch(). But this means that never anything will happen, even if You need it.